# Solving a nonlinear integral equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, integral-equations

I wonder if Mathematica can be used to numerically solve the following nonlinear integral equation?

$\lambda^2(t)-\frac{1}{\lambda^4(t)}+\frac{2}{R_0^2} \int_{R_0}^{R_0+u_0t} R    \left[\frac{\lambda^2(t)}{\lambda^4\big(\frac{R-R_0}{u_0}\big)}-\frac{\lambda^2\big(\frac{R-R_0}{u_0}\big)}{\lambda^4(t)} \right]dR =F(t)\,,\quad t\in[0,T]$,
where $R_0$, $u_0$, and $F(t)$ are given.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: May be we can solve it with Mathematica. If $R_0, u_0, F(t)$ are given then how they look like?

Comment: I suggest you try converting this to an ODE, which I believe is possible.  In any case, please provide values for your many constants and for the function, `F`.

Answer (score 6):

This integral equation can be transformed into a system of ODEs, after which it can be solved with `NDSolve`.  Begin with the integral equation,

```
eqi = λ[t]^2 - λ[t]^-4 + (2 r0^-2) (λ[t]^2 i1[t] - λ[t]^-4 i2[t]) == f[t]
```

where `i1[t]` and `i2[t]` are integrals of `r λ[(r - r0)/u0]^-4` and `r λ[(r - r0)/u0]^2`, respectively, over `{r, r0, r0 + u0 t}`.  Derivatives of these two are

```
di1 = D[i1[t], t] /. 
    i1 -> Function[t, Integrate[r λ[(r - r0)/u0]^-4, {r, r0, r0 + u0 t}]]
di2 = D[i2[t], t] /. 
    i2 -> Function[t, Integrate[r λ[(r - r0)/u0]^2, {r, r0, r0 + u0 t}]]
(* (u0 (r0 + t u0))/λ[t]^4 *)
(* u0 (r0 + t u0) λ[t]^2 *)
```

Once `f[t]` and the various constants are specified, the integral equation can be solved by

```
NDSolve[{eqi, i1'[t] = di1, i2'[t] == di2, i1[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0},
    λ[t], {t, 0, T}]
```

Alternatively, `i1[t]` and `i2[t]` can be eliminated to yield a single second-order ODE,

```
Simplify[di1 == First@Simplify@D[SolveValues[eqi, i1[t]], t] /. i2'[t] -> di2];
eq = Simplify[di2 == First@Simplify@D[SolveValues[%, i2[t]], t]]
(* u0 (r0 + t u0) λ[t]^2 == (1/(12 [λ'[t]^2)) r0^2 λ[t]^3 
  (3 λ[t] f'[t] λ'[t]^2 - 8 f[t] λ'[t]^3 + λ[t]^2 (λ'[t] f''[t] - f'[t] y''[t])) *)
```

although initial conditions for `λ[t]` also are needed.

```
eqi /. t -> 0 /. {i1[0] -> 0, i2[0] -> 0}
(* -(1/λ[0]^4) + λ[0]^2 == f[0] *)

Solve[D[eqi, t] /. {i1'[t] -> di1, i2'[t] -> di2} /. t -> 0 
    /. {i1[0] -> 0, i2[0] -> 0}, λ'[0]] [[1, 1]]
(* λ'[0] -> (λ[0]^5 f'[0])/(2 (2 + λ[0]^6)) *)
```

As an example,

```
NDSolveValue[{eqi, i1'[t] == di1, i2'[t] == di2, i1[0] == 0, i2[0] == 0} /. 
    {r0 -> 1, u0 -> 1, f[t] -> Sin[t]}, {λ[t], i1[t], i2[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
Plot[%[[1]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, λ}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
Plot[Evaluate[%%[[2 ;;]]], {t, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {t, i}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

[image]

The second-order ODE with constants as above and initial conditions `{λ[0] == 1, λ'[0] == 1/6}` gives the same result for `λ[t]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The key idea was to transform it to a system of linear ODEs.

Comment: @Arash That is correct.  If you found the answer helpful, please up-vote and accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: It was certainly helpful. This was actually my first question/post here. And I just up-voted.